# How to enable/disable macro expansion in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

Some of the machines in our office when compiling projects in XCode will flag build errors because they are doing macro expansion and finding legitimate errors.  Other machines don't do the expansion and don't catch these errors.  There must be an option to enable/disable this somewhere in XCode.  I cannot find it, is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Every machine should build all of the code, right?  Or do you have system specific `#ifdef`s in there?

Comment: There are ifdefs in a bunch of spots for sure but I've tried building the same build configurations on at least two machines.  One does the macro expansion and flags the error the other does not.

Comment: Can you show us one of these macros that gets sometimes expanded and sometimes not?  That seems like crazy talk to me.  How can the code build at all unless all of the macros it cares about get expanded?

Comment: You're right it is crazy talk.  This was my fault and it was because of a preprocessor def.  In one case the macro will expand to a typed constant whereas the other case which I use most of the time the macro expanded out to a function call with the constant as a string parameter.  So in one case I get  int myConstant  which the compiler will flag if there is a problem.  In the other case it would be  myFunc("myConstant")  which would not flag a compiler error.  Thanks for making me realize how foolish I am.  Cheers.

Comment: Good to hear it's working!

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault and it was because of a preprocessor def. In one case the macro will expand to a typed constant whereas the other case which I use most of the time the macro expanded out to a function call with the constant as a string parameter. So in one case I get `int myConstant` which the compiler will flag if there is a problem. In the other case it would be `myFunc("myConstant")` which would not flag a compiler error.